# Magento 1.7 Reindexing doesn't work for product prices

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I cannot reindex Product Prices from magento admin panel

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7bec5e01e314f80cce1226696b6b29edc' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:238 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(283): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(433): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #2 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(230): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `se...', Array) #3 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(511): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `se...', Array) #4 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(924): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sessions', Array) #5 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Session/SaveHandler/DbTable.php(354): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->insert(Array) #6 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Session/SaveHandler.php(48): Zend_Session_SaveH in /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 238
```

Answer (score 0):

For which table is this error? And what is the query which leads to the error?

I just repaired a dump from a customer. When you find you, were the error is raised and what the query is, you find the problem.

I found tier-prices in `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` which were already deleted.